# How to save/convert and read image in python with defined values for colors

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm saving, converting to grayscale, and opening an image in Python with PIL like this

```
Image.open(imgname).convert('L').save(imgname)
```

And I get a matrix with one number per pixel. My image is has 3 colors. 255 for white, 0 for black and 128 for gray.

Is there anyway that when I convert my image to grayscale I can have 0 for white, 1 for gray and 2 for black when I read this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom lut (lookup table) and apply it to the grayscale image with the `point()` method just before saving it. Gray levels in the image besides 0, 128, and 255 will remain unchanged. You could, of course, change that by initializing the table differently.

```
lut = range(256)  # initialize to an identity lut
lut[0]   = 2
lut[128] = 1
lut[255] = 0
Image.open(imgname).convert('L').point(lut).save(imgname)
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the right values for the matrix it seems, when i read the image. but when i save the image i get a black image... any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Grayscale images comprised of only values in the range 0-2 will appear very, very, dark visually because all the values in them are so low. In an 8-bit image, the values range from 0-255 which represent shades or intensities of white from nothing (which is pure black) to 100%.

Comment: Its solved! Since I needed to read the image later I just saved it without the point method as before so it got the colors right and then I did the table thing and used the point method for reading the image.